# What is the difference between declaring a variable using auto and using the type-name?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, I have some class `DataPacket`. What is the difference between:

```
auto packet = DataPacket();
```

and

```
DataPacket packet;
```

?

Comment: No difference really. The first is more verbose to no advantage so I'd opt for the second. Corrected above by Jonathan Wakeley.

Comment: The latter is backwards compatible with C++03 and more conventional.

Comment: There's really no point in having an "auto" tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer the question about `auto` first, there is no difference in the generated code between:

```
auto packet = DataPacket();
```

and

```
DataPacket packet = DataPacket();
```

But that's not what you wrote.

In the original question, the first one creates a **value-initialized** temporary and then copy-initializes `packet` from it. That requires an accessible, non-explicit copy or move constructor, requires the type can be default-constructed, **and ensures `packet` is initialized** (assuming the copy/move constructor isn't buggy.)  The second one default-initializes `packet` which only requires that the type can be default-constructed, but leaves the object uninitialized if it has a trivial default constructor, for example:

```
struct DataPacket { int i; };
{
  DataPacket packet = DataPacket();
  ++packet.i;  // OK
}
{
  DataPacket packet;
  ++packet.i;  // undefined behaviour
}
```

As Xeo points out in a comment below, these is *less* difference between these:

```
auto packet = DataPacket();

DataPacket packet{};
```

because the second of those also ensures value-initialization, so in that case the difference is that the former requires an accessible, non-explicit copy or move constructor.

In all the cases that require an accessible copy/move constructor, if the copy (or move) isn't [elided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) then the code generated will be different because of the copy/move.  But in practice it will be elided by all modern compilers so the generated code will be identical.

Comment: Obligatory remark: You can ensure value-initialization for the second one too with `DataPacket dp{};`.

Comment: @David: But but but...! This is tagged C++11... :(

Comment: Does the first one actually use the copy constructor, or is this a case where RVO kicks in?

Comment: @MooingDuck, see the last paragraph. There's no "return value" here, but [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) applies. The RVO is a special case of copy elision.

Comment: @Xeo `DataPacket dp{};` performs value initialization only if `DataPacket` doesn't have a list constructor. If there is a `DataPacket(std::initializer_list<whatever>)` constructor, `DataPacket dp{};` performs list initialization instead of value initialization.

Comment: @FredOverflow, no, if it has a default constructor that is called, see [dcl.init.list]/3 "If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized."

Comment: @JonathanWakely Oh, interesting!

Answer (score 10):

The first one is copy-initialization, and will fail if no copy or move constructor is accessible.

Comment: The first will prefer the move constructor over the copy constructor.

Comment: @ildjarn: True, but the Standard still uses the term "copy-initialization".

Comment: Also, a copy/move constructor marked `explicit` will fail (I'm not sure if "accessible" was referring to that).

Answer (score 4):

From the compiler's point of view there is no difference, other than that you can specify a parent type for the variable if you declare it explicitly.  Stylistically it affects readability (although whether it's a positive or negative effect depends on the person).

Edit:
As was pointed out, the first one does a copy construction while the second uses the default constructor.  Pedantic explanation of the differences found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402).

Comment: There _is_ a difference in the OP's particular example -- the first is copy-initialized from a value-initialized object, the second is default-initialized (for a POD type these will produce very different results).

Comment: I think the copy-initialisation can be optimised away by the compiler. Assuming both compile, the result will be the same.

Comment: @jcoe : The copy-initialization is not the issue -- default-initialization vs. value-initialization is (the behavior is very different for POD types).

Comment: @jcoe, no, if the type is a POD then value-initialization will zero it out, default initialization leaves it uninitialized, which is what ildjarn is referring to. Whether the copy is elided doesn't change that.

Comment: @ildjarn, I think you should write an answer, none of the existing ones includes your correct and important observation

Comment: @Jonathan : You can, I'll upvote it. :-] (I've already spent more time on SO today than I should have.)

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely : I never knew that default and value initialisation differed for types where no constructor is specified. Simple test confirms it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The auto keyword can be useful when you do not know the type of some expression.  You are essentially asking the compiler to determine the variable's type at compile time.  There is absolutely no difference between using the auto keyword and using the type explicitly as far as the compiler is concerned.

You can also use the auto keyword to determine the return type of a function, whose return type is not known until compile time (happens with some templated functions).  See this Wikipedia article: [Alternative function syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax).

Note that the auto keyword does NOT give you RTTI.  The auto-type is determined statically at compile time.

Back in the old C days, the auto keyword declared that the variable would have "automatic" storage on the stack, as opposed to being stored in the static data area.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest using the second syntax (without the "auto" keyword), since it is less verbose.

This is one example where auto makes sense:

```
map<int, pair<string, double>> M;
.... // Fill up M
// Without "auto":
map<int, pair<string, double> >::iterator it = M.find(5);
// With "auto":
auto autoit = M.find(5);
// Yet another example:
// Without auto:
for (pair<const int, pair<string, double>>& x: M) {
   // Do stuff
}
// With auto:
for (auto& x : M) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I am new to Stackoverflow, and didn't really understand why I received so many downvotes. Thanks!  (I've read the answers for other questions several times, but I am new to actually answering)

Comment: I've downvoted all the answers which say there's no difference, because there is a difference (unrelated to `auto` though). And to be fair, the rest of your answer is useful - I'll undownvote it if you edit out the "no difference at all" part